# xamarin custom navigation bar

Tags: android, xamarin, navigationbar

i tried to have a search bar in a navigation bar. I did it with this code:

```
public class NavigationSearchRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    private SearchView _searchView;
    public NavigationSearchRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var navPage = Element as NavigationSearchPage;
        if (navPage == null)
            return;

        var activity = this.Context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
        if (activity == null)
            return;

        var toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        _searchView = new SearchView(Context);
        toolbar.AddView(_searchView);
    }

}
```

It works but now all navigations bar have the search bar and I want only pages who inherit from NavigationSearchPage.

I also indicated the export like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationSearchPage), typeof(NavigationSearchRenderer))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works but now all navigations bar have the search bar and I want only pages who inherit from NavigationSearchPage.

All your pages have search bar because when you are navigating, the NavigationPage never get refreshed. And since your renderer only add SearchView to the Toolbar and never clear it. The SearchView you added will always be there.

**Solution:**

1. Modify this Renderer to render all your Pages in your Project, you can use the super class as the first argument of `ExportRenderer`. for example if all your pages are of type `ContentPage` then register your Renderer like this:

   ```
   [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage),
     typeof(NavigationSearchRenderer))]
   ```
2. Modify your `OnElementChanged` to add `SearchView` when `NavigationSearchPage` and clear `SearchView` when other page:

   ```
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       var activity = this.Context as FormsAppCompatActivity;
       if (activity == null)
           return;

       if (Element is NavigationSearchPage)
       {
           var toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
           _searchView = new SearchView(Context);
           toolbar.AddView(_searchView);
       }
       else
       {
           var page = (Element as ContentPage);
           if (page == null)
           {
               return;
           }
           var toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
           int count = toolbar.ChildCount;
           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
           {
               Android.Views.View child =toolbar.GetChildAt(i);
               if (child is SearchView)
               {
                   toolbar.RemoveView(child);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```